# Why doesn't enter work when submitting a form in  IE6?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, submit, form-submit, enter

(I just finished developing my new site and I am testing if it works in all browsers. I need everything to be perfect.)

I have a form:

```
<form action="example.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="example">
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Everything in this form works fine in Chrome, Opera and FF, But in IE6 it doesn't.
When I press enter, it doesn't do anything. The form doesn't get submitted.
So I have to go over to the submit button with my mouse and click it if I want to submit.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Is that really your code of the form? That should work on hitting enter.

Comment: The given example works as expected in IE6. Do you use some Javascript on the page? Do you use regular IE6 or some third-party solution like IETester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for Javascript that might be preventing you from achieving the expected behavior.

And please, consider dropping support for IE 6. **IT IS ALREADY 10 YEARS OLD**!!!!!!

Comment: if only dropping IE6 was an option all the time. If a client wants to support IE6 all we can do is tell them it is (getting) obsolete. And keep on supporting IE6 if it is still wanted.

Comment: When a client is clueless about web-development, it is our responsibility to educate them and show them why it is no longer supported.
If the client is that idiot and wont understand, in a meeting show him the reality and how IE6 breaks the most popular sites and won‘t work with most of the technologies used nowadays.
If the client still wants support, add a clause in the contract where you are free‘d from any responsibility if the site breaks in the future.

Comment: It is clear that you haven't worked with clients a lot... Not my clients at least :)

Comment: I have, for about 5 years. Only with mine ;)

Comment: @Mario Have you tried telling your clients something like "Okay, see, there's a browser that requires some additional work and I'm too lazy or incapable to resolve the issues. Would you mind dropping support for this browser which will cause loss of visitors and thus lower profit?" I'm almost sure nobody would approve.

Comment: @duri Target audience of my clients are not grandpas still on ancient machines running Windows ME, so I haven’t.